# Is there a word or phrase for teaching someone a bad thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Say a father want to teach his children a lesson by giving an example of a behavior or thing that is immoral or illegal. Or imagine a teenager want to teach his or her friend a rude action and you as his or her best friend want to advice him or her not to do that. Or a TV program that isn't suitable for children.

How can I as a mother or best friend, tell them that what you are teaching or the example you are giving may have a bad impact on them because they will learn something (like using drugs) that they may want to try that because of the natural curiosity of human being?

I am looking for a word that means "the way of teaching, especially to children, where you teach someone something immoral or illegal not on purpose."

Comment: It's "detrimental" to their learning

Comment: It sounds like to are talking about "setting a bad example", but your post is a little unclear.

Comment: In principle the father would be ***corrupting*** his children, but that's a bit strong for many contexts. Perhaps he's ***leading them astray***. It's really a matter of opinion which expressions suit which contexts.

Comment: it sounds like that would be a “dangerous and irresponsible approach” to their education.

Comment: The OP is somewhat confusing, but I think the example is supposed to be of a bad thing to avoid, not a bad thing to indulge in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bad lesson was unintentional, the words could be *misteach* or *misinstruct*.

> The father mistaught his son about gun safety.
>
> The priest was found to be misinstructing the boys about the violence used by Joshua.

Also, misguide could be the word.

> The mother misguided her daughter as to the Birds and the Bees.

In some contexts, misinform will work.

> Billy misinformed Johnny as to when he needed to be back in class.

Comment: I think [mis-instruction](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misinstruction) is close to the word in my language. Thanks.